# Getting random symbols when printing user input

Tags: assembly, dos

I am trying to learn assembly and I wanted to create a simple program, where user inputs something and the program just prints out what he just input. Everything works fine until I am printing the input, I get a lot of trash symbols instead of the input

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    info db "Enter a string $"
    buffer db 10, ?, 10 dup(" ")
.code

start:
    MOV dx, @data
    MOV ds, dx

    mov ah, 09h ;printing info
    lea dx, info
    int 21h

    mov ah, 0Ah ;reading input
    lea dx, buffer
    int 21h

    mov ah, 09h ;printing the input
    lea dx, buffer
    int 21h

    mov ah, 4ch
    mov al, 0
    int 21h

end start
```

Am I doing something wrong with printing the input?

Comment: Notice that the actual input starts at `buffer+2`. Also, the print function expects a `$` terminator which the input does not provide. Simple fix is to fill your buffer with `$` instead of spaces (and add an extra one in case you get 10 characters).